# Responisive DIVs with CSS-toggle-effect: Strange behaviour in Firefox, all other browsers are OK?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, toggle

I made a menu with Jquery containing several words and pictures. It works fine in all browsers, except Firefox. If you hover the third item (always the last one, because every item is ~ 30% width) there is a strange effect happening that I can´t explain.

Could you have a look at my fiddle and can you help me to solve this problem?
Many many thanks in advance :-))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lvl3 li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".lvl3-hover").toggle(10);
        $(this).find(".lvl3-pic-hover").toggle(10);
        $(this).find(".lvl3-title-hover").toggle(10);
        $(this).find(".lvl3-title").toggle(10);
        $(this).find(".lvl3-subtitle-hover").toggle(10);
        $(this).find(".lvl3-subtitle").toggle(10);
        $(this).find(".lvl3-projektdetails").toggle(10);
    });
});
```

[see my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rheingau360/HNUWZ/2/)

**Edit:**

This was what I tried first, only toggling the `<div>` that should appear on hover. The flickering is better then, but when I hover the third element (maybe you must resize your browser window a little bit to see it), there is a strange "jump" in my menu.

I'm trying for hours getting this away but I didn't find a solution, yet.

Could you check this again?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lvl3 li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".lvl3-hover").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is (yet) but I think the CSS and jQuery is overly complex. You should be able to just change the `display` of the parent rather than manipulating the display of all the elements you want to _hover_. This approach is also very expensive and makes the hover effect slow in some browsers.

Comment: It's almost certainly a combination of the `float` and floating point rounding errors that are causing the jumping element. Which browsers does this need to work in? There are cleaner solutions to hovering elements that do not require a transparent background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem in Chrome as well although I was seeing the elements jump (and return) quicker. I believe this was due to floating point rounding errors but honestly the HTML, CSS and JavaScript were overly complex I decided that the simpler solution would involve more than rounding some length values. So, although it might not be exactly what you are after, I am seeing the expected behaviour in Firefox and Chrome. I can't test IE unfortunately.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZkcD/)

I tidied up/messed around with the HTML and CSS to solve the problem by just using the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ahover) pseudo-class for the hover effect and rounded all of the percentage lengths, so it will not be an *exactly* identical layout.

Also, this can be solved without any JavaScript!

**HTML**

```
<ul class="lvl3">
    <li>
        <a href="1" target="_self">
            <div class="lvl3-normal">
                <div class="lvl3-pic"></div>
                <div class="lvl3-title">Test</div>
                <div class="lvl3-subtitle">Frankfurt</div>
            </div>
            <div class="lvl3-hover"></div>
            <div class="lvl3-projektdetails">&rarr; Projektdetails</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="1" target="_self">
            <div class="lvl3-normal">
                <div class="lvl3-pic"></div>
                <div class="lvl3-title">Test</div>
                <div class="lvl3-subtitle">Munich</div>
            </div>
            <div class="lvl3-hover"></div>
            <div class="lvl3-projektdetails">&rarr; Projektdetails</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="1" target="_self">
            <div class="lvl3-normal">
                <div class="lvl3-pic"></div>
                <div class="lvl3-title">Test</div>
                <div class="lvl3-subtitle">Cologne</div>
            </div>
            <div class="lvl3-hover"></div>
            <div class="lvl3-projektdetails">&rarr; Projektdetails</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="1" target="_self">
            <div class="lvl3-normal">
                <div class="lvl3-pic"></div>
                <div class="lvl3-title">Test</div>
                <div class="lvl3-subtitle">Hamburg</div>
            </div>
            <div class="lvl3-hover"></div>
            <div class="lvl3-projektdetails">&rarr; Projektdetails</div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.lvl3 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display:block;
}

.lvl3 li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0.83%;
    margin-right: 0.83%;
    margin-bottom: 0.83%;
    width: 31%;
    position: relative;
}

.lvl3-normal {
    background-color: #f0f0f5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 83%;
}

.lvl3-hover {
    background-color:#ee7029;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 53%;
    display: none;
    opacity:.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

.lvl3-pic {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 53%;
    background-image:url(http://p183853.webspaceconfig.de/uploads/media/objekt_10.jpg);
}

.lvl3-title {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ee7029;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lvl3-subtitle {
    margin-left: 2%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #022236;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.lvl3-projektdetails {
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 20% 10% 0 10%;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
    display:none;
}

a:hover .lvl3-hover, a:visited .lvl3-hover, a:hover .lvl3-projektdetails, a:visited .lvl3-projektdetails  {
    display: block;
}

a:hover .lvl3-normal, a:visited .lvl3-normal  {
    background-color:#ee7029;
}

a:hover .lvl3-title, a:visited .lvl3-title {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Also please note that the markup would benefit from further tidying and I would also look towards using a more semantic markup, for example using a heading element instead of a `<div>` styled as a title.

Hope this helps.